# How to combine tf.map_fn and tf.split

Tags: python, tensorflow

So the pseucode of thing i want is:

```
splitted_outputs = [tf.split(output, rate, axis=0) for output in outputs]
```

where outputs is Tensor of shape (512, ?, 128), and splitted_outputs is list of lists of Tensors or Tensor with 3 dimensions. So i can iterate such tensor tensorflow.

I've tried to use `tf.map_fn`:

```
splitted_outputs = tf.map_fn(
    lambda output: tf.split(output, rate, axis=0),
    outputs,
    dtype=list
)
```

but it's not possible cause `list` is not legal tf `dtype`.

Comment: What is `outputs`, a tensor? If so, what is the shape? What would you like to get in `splitted_outputs`, a list of lists?

Comment: @jdehesa i've updated question

Comment: i know that it's a weird desire but i have to make some such manipulations with output tensor

Comment: You can do `splitted_outputs = [tf.split(output, rate, axis=0) for output in tf.unstack(outputs, axis=0)]`

Comment: @jdehesa Would you like to make it as answer so i can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/usntack) on `outputs` to get a list of "subtensors", then use [`tf.split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) on each of those:

```
splitted_outputs = [tf.split(output, rate, axis=0) for output in tf.unstack(outputs, axis=0)]
```

Note that [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/usntack) can only be used like that when the size of the given `axis` is known, or otherwise you would need to provide a `num` parameter.